# Storing images in custom data attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `h3` tag thats wrapping a `img` tag and the text. It works but I feel like its a really bad idea to do. Example:

```
<h3> 
  <img src="dir/to/image.jpg" alt="icon" />
  Heading text
</h3>
```

I was reading about HTML5 custom data attributes (`data-*`) and then I remembered that I saw a tutorial on some website a while back ago that was using custom data attributes to store the icons and showing them beside the text (`data-icon`). This is exactly what I need.

Problem is I can't figure out how to output the image. How would I do this? Possibly with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `content: attr(data-icon)` to output the image ([other uses of the content property](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-generated-content-techniques/))

Comment: Nice link. I enjoyed your article on using the css property `content`, and especially the point you make about `content` being viable in an IE8+ environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [data:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) URL scheme? The data scheme allows you to embed the image data right in the URL:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg[bunch of base64 omitted]Jggg=="/>
```

Presumably you could store the data URL in a `data-icon` attribute and then copy it to `src` using jQuery when you need it:

```
<h3 data-icon="data:image/png:base64,...."><img/>Dot!</h3>
```

and then elsewhere:

```
$('h3').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('img:first').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-icon'));
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img:first').attr('src', '');
    }
 );
```

Of course you could add the `<img/>` tag in the jQuery stuff too but I'm trying to keep it simple for illustrative purposes.

AFAIK, browser support is okay for simple uses as long as you stay away from IE versions less than 8.